# How to get the chemical form of the Lotka-Volterra ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I know how to work from a chemical equation to an ODE, as described here:

http://brunel.ac.uk/~cspgoop/uploads/ode_chemical_network.pdf

How do I go the other way? I want to convert the Lotka-Volterra ODE system to chemical equations so I can use it in a cell simulation program.

Comment: Do this first for some simple polynomial scalar equations to get a feel, e.g. $\dot{x} = ax - bx^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is direct if one analyzes the dynamics Lotka-Volterra systems are supposed to model: some population $X$ of preys, some population $Y$ of predators, in isolation preys reproduce and predators die, and when in contact predators kill preys and multiply.

This fits the system of "chemical" reactions $$X\to2X,\qquad Y\to Z,\qquad X+Y\to2Y,$$ where $Z$ is a junk species accounting for the dead predators.

Minor caveat: the rates $(a,b,c)$ of the three "reactions" above yield the differential equations $$X'=aX-cXY,\qquad Y'=-bY+cXY,\tag{$\ast$}$$ hence, to solve/simulate the general system $$X'=aX-cXY,\qquad Y'=-bY+dXY,$$ depending on four rates $(a,b,c,d)$, one should consider "reduced" populations $$((c/d)X,Y),$$ where $(X,Y)$ solves $(\ast)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, why isn't there a few squared terms because of the 2 in the first and third equations?

Comment: Scalar factors on the RHS of the chemical reactions translate into scalar factors of the concentrations, not into powers. The reaction $A+3B\to2C+5D$ at rate $r$, say, contributes for $-rA\cdot B^3$ in $A'$, for $-3rA\cdot B^3$ in $B'$, for $2rA\cdot B^3$ in $C'$ and for $5rA\cdot B^3$ in $D'$.